# Populate listview with a spinner

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-spinner

I'm having difficulty with my app right now. Currently I have my app setup where when the user clicks on a button it then gets a new spinner. The problem with this is the user can not delete the spinner if they dont want the food item.

Problem: I'm trying to find good resources that have sample code or tutorial that would help me with this. I want the listview to be populated with my  spinner.

When the user selects a item in the spinner they then click on a button which saves it and populates it in the listview.

This is what my app looks like right now:

[image: app current state]

updated picture two:

[image]

here is my current xml

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:weightSum="1">


     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/title"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/BLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:text="@string/breakfast"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:id="@+id/bkSpinner"
        android:layout_weight="0.21"
        android:entries="@array/allFoodItems" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addNewBItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/BButton"
        android:layout_column="13"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/BLL"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addNewDItem"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/addNewDItem"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />


      </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/addNewDItem"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

        android:layout_marginTop="127dp"
        android:text="Lunch"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:id="@+id/LSpinner"
        android:layout_weight="0.21"
        android:entries="@array/allFoodItems"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addNewLItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="@string/LButton"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
       </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/DLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/LLL"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/LLL"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addNewDItem">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:paddingBottom="130dp"
        android:text="@string/dinner"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/LLL"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/LLL"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:id="@+id/dnSpinner"
        android:entries="@array/allFoodItems" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addNewDItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="@string/DButton"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>


 <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="2.31">




<Button
    android:id="@+id/total"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/totalCal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/calories"
android:layout_width="94dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
   </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Thank you once again for taking the time and reading my problem. I'm just freaking out since I'm stick and my project is due next week.

Comment: upload your work here

Comment: it must be a problem with your `spinner layout`, upload your work here so that we can help you

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya I just uploaded the xml I have. I tried switching to LinearLayout instead of Relative and it still looked funky. It was all spaced out .

Comment: What would I need to do so that the user can select an item n the spinner and when clicking button it populates listview .

do you know of a good tutorial or maybe a sample code